# did:$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2 + \frac{1}{x} )- \sin(\frac{1}{x}))}{x}$

Tags: calculus

Could you guys give me at least a hint at:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2 + \frac{1}{x}) - \sin(\frac{1}{x}))}{x}$$
? I already tried expanding the $\sin(x^2 + \frac{1}{x})$ but got nothing. Also, changing variables would not work because when $x\to 0$, $\frac{1}{x}\to\infty$ and I'm not allowed yet to use limits to infinity.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answers, I did:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2 + \frac{1}{x}) - \sin(\frac{1}{x}))}{x} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\color{Blue}{\sin(\frac{x^2}{2})}  \cos(\frac{x^2 + \frac{2}{x}}{2})\frac{x}{2}}{\color{Blue}{\frac{x^2}{2}}} =  \color{Blue}{1} \cdot \lim_{x\to0}\cos(\frac{x^2+\frac{2}{x}}{2})\cdot\frac{x}{2} = 0$$
becuse we have a bounded function $\cos(\frac{x^2+\frac{2}{x}}{2})$ and a function that goes to $0$: $\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: (neither l'hospital rule...)

Comment: Are you allowed to use derivatives whatsoever?

Comment: @DanZimm nope :c

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\sin\left(x^2+\frac1x\right)-\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=\sin\left(\frac1x\right)(\cos(x^2)-1)+\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\sin(x^2)$$

now since $$\cos(x^2)-1\sim_0-\frac{x^2}2$$
and 
$$\sin(x^2)\sim_0 x^2$$
and the fact that the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are bounded we see readily that the desired limit is $0$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Convert the numerator to product using the identity
$$ \sin p - \sin q = 2 \sin \frac{p-q}{2} \cos\frac{p+q}{2}$$
I think this is the simplest approach.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this right? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Marter Js According to the identity, in your answer, the second sin in the numerator must be cos ...

Comment: I changed. Cosine is also bounded. Is this right now?

Comment: Yes, but you have $\cos(\frac{x^2+\frac{2}{x}}{2})$...

Comment: that's right. Thanks :)